# Где нужно разрешать конфликты?

Tags: git, github

Над проектом работает 5 человек. Репозиторий на GitHub. Все используют Git через консоль. Я веду проект, другие разработчики отправляют свои ветки, на GitHub создаю pull request, и делаю слияние с веткой `master`.
Стали возникать случаи сложных конфликтов. Разрешать их через веб-интерфейс GitHub неудобно.

Cебе локально установил Sublime Merge, в котором удобно сделан функционал разрешения конфликтов. Как я могу этим локальным инструментом создавать pull request? Каким образом мне ветки других разработчиков объединять с `master`?

Должен ли я забрать все ветки с GitHub, через `fetch` и делать merge с `master`? Нужно ли мне тогда выполнять `push master`? Как результат вернуть на GitHub?

Comment: Вам что-то мешает делать push master или в чём проблема?

Comment: А в вебе можно разрешать конфликты? О_о

Comment: Ну для начала другие разработчики вполне могут создавать PR самостоятельно и сами же разрешать конфликты. А вообще что-то у вас неправильно в процессе если сложные конфликты возникают часто

Comment: @AlexeyTen просто приходится часто работать над одним файлом. В будущем думаем разделить файл на несколько. Но пока вопрос именно в том, как локально разрешать конфликты?

Comment: @andreymal а если что-то не то в мастер попало? Что-то непротестированное?

Comment: @234234 поэтому пуш в мастер должен быть только у ответственных людей, которые всё тщательно протестируют перед пушем. В настройках репозитория гитхаба это вроде настраивается

Comment: Стали возникать случаи сложных конфликтов - это признак того, что вы мержите редко, или пытаетесь делать работу большими кусками. Или работаете одновременно над одним и тем же куском кода в рамках совсем разных задач.

Comment: Вариант, к которому я привыкла: разработчик делает PR, видит конфликт, стягивает себе свежего мастера и делает `git merge master` или `git pull --rebase origin master` из своей ветки, после этого форспушит ветку обратно на гитхаб. Если долго работаешь над веткой (это плохо, я знаю), то делаешь так раз в несколько дней